# What is the correct markup for Bundle or Grouped Products

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, google-rich-snippets, structured-data

Hello I have bundle products on my Magento site and want to make sure I'm implemening the best/recommedned way to markup for search engines...

Example page here - https://fernland.com.au/bamboo-stakes-120cm-10-12mmo-7712.html
As you can see the bundle product is setup more like a grouped product would behave, where a customer would select only one of the options (each option is a simple product that can be purchased separately)

This is what I'm thinking of implementing - is this the recommend way - (there is very little info out there for this sort of situation.)

```
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Product",
  "name": "Bundle_Name",
  "sku": "Bundle_SKU",
  "url":"Bundle_URL",
  "brand": "Bundle_Brand",
  "image": "Bundle_Main_Image_URL",
  "description":"BundleDescription",
  "category":"Bundle_Category",
  "offers": [{
    "@type": "Offer",
    "sku": "CHILD_SKU",
    "url":"Bundle_URL",
    "image": "Simple_Product_Main_Image_URL",
    "name": "Simple_Product_Child_Name",
    "price": 5.99,
    "priceCurrency": "AUD",
    "availability": "InStock"
  },{
    "@type": "Offer",
    "sku": "CHILD_SKU",
    "url":"Bundle_URL",
    "image": "Simple_Product_Main_Image_URL",
    "name": "Simple_Product_Child_Name",
    "price": 10.99,
    "priceCurrency": "AUD",
    "availability": "OutOfStock"
  },{
    "@type": "Offer",
    "sku": "CHILD_SKU",
    "url":"Bundle_URL",
    "image": "Simple_Product_Main_Image_URL",
    "name": "Simple_Product_Child_Name",
    "price": 17.99,
    "priceCurrency": "AUD",
    "availability": "InStock"
  }]
}
```

Appreciate your help!